# SQL User without login connection string

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I recently found out about "user with no login" . We have a third party developer who needs access to our data on our SQL server. I thought that creating a user with no login would allow the third party access ( to the parts that they need ) without giving them a password. If they have a password, they could login via SSMS and I didn't want that ( I think, I am new to DBA work ) . So what would be the connection string be ? Just fill in the "user = " part ?
The SQL database is on an EC2 instance. Using Lambda.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking here? In a non-contained database a `USER` without a `LOGIN` can't be used by connecting to the instance (database); it's known as an "orphaned user". These do have some uses, often in relation to impersonation and permission testing/demonstrating, however, I doubt that is what you are after. If the person needs access to the database, and the database isn't contained, they will need a `LOGIN`  at the instance level and `USER` at the database level. Just ensure you give the user the smallest amount of permissions they need.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I had read about this and they even used the name 'ApplicationDeveloperLogin' , but I guess I misunderstood it's use.  I can't vote because you used a comment, but this is the correct answer. I will lock then down.